# Can't do-release-upgrade -d from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

Tried `do-release-upgrade -d` on a 16.04 machine today but got

```
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

Surely LTS to LTS is allowed?

Result of `cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` is `Prompt=lts`

Comment: 15 days is not too long, you can wait for official release. My clean 16.04 LTS says that bionic is available. Check your `cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades | grep Prompt` (my has `lts`).

Comment: It's set for LTS.

Comment: @OrganicMarble can you include the output of `cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` here?  This should be working, but something might be amiss on your system specifically preventing you from doing the direct upgrade attempt.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy ubuntu-release-upgrader-core`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: This turned out to be a connection problem with a terribly un-informative error message.

Answer (score 4):

Remove any files in `~/.cache/update-manager-core/` and try the upgrade process again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and have my upvote. This turned out to be a connection problem with a terribly un-informative error message.

Comment: Had the same problem, this fixed it for me. Thanks.